# How to make HibernateValidator pick up Locale from HTTP request Header for measage templates in spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, locale, hibernate-validator

I've been cracking my head on this problem for a week. After deep research and debugging session I'm just desperate.

All want to do is for the `HibernateValidator` to pick up messages from the provided `MessageSource` and use locale to interpolate messages from the `MessageSource` according to the template provided in the annotation for the object field.

So far the only thing `HibernateValidator` does is falling back to the `Locale.getDefault()` every time no matter what I do.

This thing where Spring developers say that there is to easy way to do that.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/20673

This is the topic that describes the setup I should use to get the result that still does not work.

[Spring Boot, Hibernate validator language based on LocaleContextHolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66951275/spring-boot-hibernate-validator-language-based-on-localecontextholder)

This is my starting setup that just work with one default locale in my case.

What do I need to add or change in order for the `HibernateValidator` to pick up `Locale` from the Header and interpolate messages from the `MessageSource` in the correct `Locale` picked up from the request header?

Here is the primitive setup I've got.

Controller.

```java
package com.example.gatewayservice.controller;

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
//@Validated
public class UserDataController {

    @Autowired
    UserDataService userDataService;

    @Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    @PostMapping("/getSimData")
//    @Validated(OnRequestValidation.class)
    public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<SimDataResponse>> getSimData(@Valid @RequestBody SimDataRequest request) {

        log.info("Entered getSimData controller with the request ::\n {}", request);

        ResponseEntity<SimDataResponse> result = ResponseEntity.ok(userDataService.getSimData(request));

        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result);
    }
}
```

Request object that is validated with Hibernate validator.

```java
package com.example.gatewayservice.dto.controller;

@Data
public class SimDataRequest {

    @NotEmpty(message = "{msisdn.error.empty}")
    private String msisdn;

}
```

messages.properties file content

```
msisdn.error.empty="MSISDN is empty"
```

messages_fr.properties file content

```
msisdn.error.empty=Le MSISDN est vide
```

And the root of all problems, the configuration that for the love of me I can't figure out.

```java
package com.example.gatewayservice.config;

@Configuration
public class ServiceConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                .writeTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                .readTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                .build();

        return restTemplateBuilder
                .requestFactory(() -> new OkHttp3ClientHttpRequestFactory(okHttpClient))
                .build();

    }

    @Bean("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public TaskExecutor asyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(50);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(1000);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(50);
        executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Async-");
        return executor;
    }



    /*locale resolution strategy*/
    @Bean
    public AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        final CustomLocaleResolver resolver = new CustomLocaleResolver();
        resolver.setSupportedLocales(Arrays.asList(Locale.FRANCE, Locale.US, Locale.UK));
        resolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return resolver;
    }

    public static class CustomLocaleResolver extends AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver {
        List<Locale> LOCALES = Arrays.asList(
                new Locale("en"),
                new Locale("fr"));
        @Override
        public Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {
            String headerLang = request.getHeader("Accept-Language");
            return headerLang == null || headerLang.isEmpty()
                    ? Locale.getDefault()
                    : Locale.lookup(Locale.LanguageRange.parse(headerLang), LOCALES);
        }
    }

    /*default message source*/
    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
//        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    /*Validator setup*/
    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();

        factoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());

//        MessageInterpolatorFactory interpolatorFactory = new MessageInterpolatorFactory(validationMessageSource());
//        factoryBean.setMessageInterpolator(interpolatorFactory.getObject());

        return factoryBean;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at the [`LocaleResolver`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-locale-resolver) provided by Hibernate Validator.

You could create a resolver that would work based on the `LocaleContextHolder` which has its locale set by the `RequestContextFilter` :

```
@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();

    factoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    factoryBean.setConfigurationInitializer( configuration -> {
        // cast to Hibernate Validator specific configuration to be able to access
        // the locale resolver:
        ( (HibernateValidatorConfiguration) configuration ).localeResolver(
                new LocaleResolver() {
                    @Override
                    public Locale resolve(LocaleResolverContext context) {
                        // use the locale from the context holder.
                        // this works with RequestContextFilter. 
                        return LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
                    }
                }
        );
    });
    return factoryBean;
}
```

If the locale resolution by that filter doesn't meet your needs, you can create your own filter and add it to the chain. The general idea remains the same - get the locale in the filter and set it to some thread local variable, and retrieve the locale in the `LocaleResolver`.